# Getting error after install drupal8?

Tags: installation, 8

I have installed [drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2311847) .

During installation i am getting the below error

```
Drupal requires you to enable the PHP extensions in the following list (see the <a href="http://drupal.org/requirements">system requirements page</a> for more information):<div class="item-list"><ul><li>fileinfo</li></ul></div>
```

Which i have solved by uncommenting "extension=php_fileinfo.dll" in php.ini file.

But after successfully installation i am getting connection reset issue like url is not found.

I know d8 is not stable version.

Still some users working/posting issue.

How they able to work on it?

Please suggest is there any alternative link to download d8.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Still some users working/posting issue. How they able to work on it?

They have set up a working web server, installed Drupal core files and a database, and configured a vhost for it. Once you've got your web server working you'll be able to work on it too. That should be your focus; check your web server error logs and fix everything that it says is wrong.

> is there any alternative link to download d8.

There might be, but why would you want to get it from somewhere other than the official Drupal repository? You wouldn't be able to trust that it was up-to-date or that integrity had been maintained with the official release (without manually checking, obviously, but that seems pointless).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Do you mean by this is my local server setting issue? if i can solve that then i can work on d8.

Comment: Almost certainly. I've been using D8 for over a year on several machines, and I know plenty of others who have been doing the same, so there shouldn't be any problem. Looks like you're on Windows, there's a pretty in-depth guide [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2068399) that may help

Comment: Yes you are right i am using windows and xampp.

Comment: I think the most important part of @Clive's answer is that you should check your web server error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using PHP 5.4 or higher per the [System Requirements](https://www.drupal.org/requirements).

Comment: It's not likely to be that; that would throw a very specific syntax error

Comment: I think @clive is right because i am already using PHP 5.4.4

Comment: @Clive, do you know what that specific syntax error message is?

Comment: I do @JohnathanElmore :) _"Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING' or `'('' in var\www\html\core\includes\bootstrap.inc on line 3"_